# How to copy one database table data to another database table sqlite3 python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

i have two database #1 is tripplanner.db and the #2 is trip.db .I want to add trip.db table 'restaurants' data to db # 1 tripplanner.db table 'restaurants'(which is empty now). I am using sqlite which is builtin in python.
Help me please.And tell me how i can execute this in python.

```
   import sqlite3

   import os

   conn = sqlite3.connect('trip.db')
   c = conn.cursor() 
   c.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS things")

   c.execute("ATTACH DATABASE ? AS db2", (os.path.join('data', 'db', 'trip_tripplanner.db'),))

   c.execute("SELECT things FROM db2.sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='things'")
   c.execute(c.fetchone()[0]) 
   c.execute("INSERT INTO trip.things SELECT * FROM db2.things")

  conn.commit() 

   conn.close()
```

This code is what i have tried so far by seeing posts in stackoverflow.but it is giving me error because i don't know what is 'data' in os.path.join('data').

Comment: What part of [`join`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) do you not understand?

Comment: os.path.join.... data is the directory of what? where the database is stored?

Comment: It's the directory that you're telling the database to use. Whether it actually is stored there, only you know.